# Left Hand Side of an Assignment must be a Variable CharAt

Tags: java, string, variable-assignment

I currently have the following code for java.

```
public class lesson8
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();

        String user;
        int length, counter, spacecounter;
        spacecounter=0;
        c.print("Enter a string. ");
        user = c.readLine();

        length = (user.length()-1);

        for (counter=0;counter<length;counter++) 
        {
            if (user.charAt(counter) = "") 
            {
                spacecounter++;
            }
        }

        c.println("There are "+spacecounter+" spaces in your string.");
        c.println("There are "+counter+" characters in your string.");

        // Place your program here.  'c' is the output console
        // main method
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on this part:

```
        if (user.charAt(counter) = "")
```

The error is

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

I changed it to "==", but now I get another error:

> The type of the left sub-expression "char" is not compatible with the type of the right sub-expression "java.lang.String".

How would I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the reason why

```
if (user.charAt(counter) = "")
```

gives that error is that "=" is an assignment operator in java, and so the left-hand side must be a variable. That being said, you probably actually want

```
if (user.charAt(counter) == ' ')
```

which uses the comparison operator (==) and the space character (' '). ("" is an empty string)

Answer (score 2):

You are using  an asignment over a comparison operator.

Change

```
if (user.charAt(counter) = "")
```

to

```
if (user.charAt(counter) == "")
```

Update:
You also have an error at comparison again. 
You should also use `single quotes ( ' )` to compare a `char`, otherwise it won't get compiled.

```
if (user.charAt(counter) == '')
```

But this too will not get compiled as a *zero* length char is not defined.
You should be comparing a valid character, say ' ' for *space*.

Comment: Actually... those "" should be ''.  Otherwise +1.

Comment: You can't have an empty character literal.  It should probably be ' ', with a space.

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the equality operator `==`, not the assignment operator `=` .

Comment: I changed it to "==", but now i get another error... the type of the left sub-expressoin "char" is not copmatible with the type of the right sub-expression "java.lang.String". How would I solve this?

Comment: Make your comparison with a character ie `' '`, not a string `""`.

Answer (score 1):

"==" is going to make sure that the value to the right is the same as the variable to the left.

"=" is an assignment operator and is used to give value TO the variable, rather than compare it.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in my code. Adding parenthesis solved this error

Changed from

```
if(isNotNullorEmpty(operator)) 
                ArrayList<String> result =  getOperatorAndTypeforName(name );
```

to

```
if(isNotNullorEmpty(operator)){ 
                ArrayList<String> result = getOperatorAndTypeforName(name );
}
```